# What would be the speed of a hypothethetical object created during the big bang

Tags: speed-of-light, universe, big-bang

What would be the speed of a hypothethetical object created during the big bang, and that has been moving around in the universe and that is now close to the earth, so the time elapsed (from the hypothetical object's perspective) is around 6,500 years, that is the age of the universe according to some people?.

Comment: So you're asking us to solve $\Delta\tau=\Delta t/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ for $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For relativistic time dilation to pull 13.8 billion years down to 6500 years, the object would have to have a Lorentz factor of $\gamma = 2 \times 10^6$, or be traveling at 0.9999999999998891 of lightspeed.

At this speed, a collision with an interstellar hydrogen atom would yield about a PeV, or 100x the energy released per collision at the LHC.  It would produce a lot of Higgs bosons in its flight around the cosmos, and would of course have to be made of unobtanium to survive. ;)

Comment: "... have to be made of unobtanium...." Ummm, are we forgetting adamantium as an alternative?

Comment: @Jim or [atomantium perhaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_Ant)? I'm showing my age here.